# How to transfer file from remote server to local machine over VPN?

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, scp, remote-desktop

I can transfer files from local to server and vice versa using scp from local machine, but my connection speed is slow on local machine and i want to use **connection speed of server** to transfer file from **server to local machine**.
Both remote server and local machine is running ubuntu 16.0.4, local machine is connected to remote server over **VPN**.
For example: I want to upload/transfer 2GB file to local machine from remote server, i can get the file by following step on local machine

```
$scp remote-user@<remote-address>:/<file-name> /home/<user>/
```

By doing above step, file will be transferred in 2 hours because downloading speed is 400kbps.

After ssh to remote:

```
$ssh remote-user@<remote-address>
```

Can i make it speedy if i upload 2GB file from remote to local because remote server connection speed is 100mbps ?

Can anyone please help me out thanks ?

Comment: If your local connection is slow, adding a VPN into the mix will not make it faster.

Comment: i want to execute scp command from remote server to local server.

Comment: if i upload file from remote server to dropbox it's so fast because server is running with high connection speed, but i want to upload/transfer from remote to my machine? Can't i achieve high speed transfer ? sorry i am not expert in networking

Comment: I am confused by the question. Are you asking if the speed between your remote and local, will be faster if you type the command on the remote, compared to if you type it locally? Edit the question to make it clear.

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: @MushahidGillani You need to think of each machine connected to the Internet by a hose and anything transferred between the two machines must go through both hoses. Therefore, even if your server hose is big(e.g. 100mbps), the data still must pass through your small local hose (400kbps). To use another metaphor, your local Internet connection is the weakest link. Also, as DopeGhoti noted, VPN can only make it slower. SCP will also be slower than FTP due to encryption overhead.

Comment: Got it, thanks @Sap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems when I was using VPN in China.

SSH/SCP, FTP, and OpenVPN were both throttled severely through the Great Firewall of China.  HTTP or HTTPS were not throttled (as long as you weren't relying on something that had any affiliation with google, facebook or other blocked service) and so some third-party transfer sites such as wetransfer worked well.  I heard some china-based VPNs also worked well.

The hose-analogy that others are describing is accurate if you don't have a route through 3rd party who may be artificially throttling your connection based on port, protocol, or content.

Which countries are your clients and servers in?  Which brand of VPN are you using?

Small interesting anecdote:  I had a redmine intranet server in the Netherlands that I connected to with OpenVPN.  However when I used it from China, it took about 2 minutes to load each page.  It turns out that the theme on the server relied on content from fonts.google.com.  Even though things should have been encrypted in OpenVPN, the great firewall still managed to detect and block most of those requests (but eventually I'd get the requested data after about two minutes of attempts).  I changed themes on the server to use only local fonts and everything worked well after that.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection from client-pc to internet is slow. Your connection from client-pc to remote-server is even slower over VPN or SSH (including SFTP and SCP). But your connection from remote-server to internet is faster. This means you are stuck with a slow connection between client-pc and the internet, and there is no way you can bypass this restriction unless you upgrade your internet package with your local ISP.